# How to filter JSON data based on date value using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON data that I want to filter based on certain value. My goal is to take min, max and icon data based on date (which is always different).

```
{
dt: 1592992800,
sunrise: 1592967182,
sunset: 1593023285,
temp: {
day: 24,
min: 18.46,
max: 24.14,
night: 18.46,
eve: 24.14,
morn: 24
},
weather: [
{
id: 500,
main: "Rain",
description: "light rain",
icon: "10d"
}
],
{
dt: 1593079200,
sunrise: 1593053602,
sunset: 1593109688,
temp: {
day: 25.46,
min: 15.65,
max: 27.63,
night: 21.54,
eve: 27.63,
morn: 15.65
},
weather: [
{
id: 800,
main: "Clear",
description: "sky is clear",
icon: "01d"
}
]
```

How can I filter **min** and **max** value based on **dt** value and display it in my div element:

```
<div class="today">
 <div class="min">
   <p class="temp_min" id="todaymin">↓17°C</p>
 </div>
 <div class="max">
   <p class="temp_max" id="todaymax">↑22°C</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First task: indent your code.

Comment: that JSON is not valid, please fix it to be a valid JSON or a JS object

Comment: I am fetching data from OpenWeatherMap API. Example like this one:https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Belgrade,rs&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
// jsonStr gets result from https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Belgrade,rs&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02

let jsonStr = '{"city":{"id":6940463,"name":"Altstadt","coord":{"lon":11.5752,"lat":48.137},"country":"DE","population":0},"cod":"200","message":0.1094425,"cnt":7,"list":[{"dt":1487242800,"temp":{"day":286.67,"min":272.78,"max":286.67,"night":273.34,"eve":277.05,"morn":281.56},"pressure":972.73,"humidity":75,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":1.81,"deg":248,"clouds":0},{"dt":1487329200,"temp":{"day":278.25,"min":275.04,"max":278.25,"night":275.04,"eve":275.64,"morn":276.48},"pressure":966.98,"humidity":95,"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"speed":3.17,"deg":262,"clouds":92,"rain":11.74,"snow":0.31},{"dt":1487415600,"temp":{"day":277.93,"min":269.55,"max":278.37,"night":269.55,"eve":273.8,"morn":274.56},"pressure":966.06,"humidity":95,"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"speed":0.86,"deg":244,"clouds":8,"snow":0.09},{"dt":1487502000,"temp":{"day":276.41,"min":267.97,"max":276.41,"night":269.77,"eve":273.57,"morn":267.97},"pressure":933.27,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":1.57,"deg":142,"clouds":74},{"dt":1487588400,"temp":{"day":276.28,"min":271.12,"max":276.28,"night":273.12,"eve":274.52,"morn":271.12},"pressure":938.21,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"speed":1.79,"deg":248,"clouds":88,"rain":0.93,"snow":0.38},{"dt":1487674800,"temp":{"day":278.1,"min":271.73,"max":278.1,"night":272.55,"eve":274.01,"morn":271.73},"pressure":945.82,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":2.19,"deg":262,"clouds":25,"snow":0.01},{"dt":1487761200,"temp":{"day":281.76,"min":273.21,"max":281.76,"night":278.88,"eve":279.22,"morn":273.21},"pressure":945.21,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.98,"deg":272,"clouds":65,"rain":1.48}]}';

let obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

var myDate = '2/16/2017'; // change it in m/d/yyyy format

let filteredResult = obj.list.filter(
  item => new Date( item.dt *1000 ).toLocaleDateString() === myDate
);

if(filteredResult && filteredResult.length) {
  console.log('Max: ' + filteredResult[0].temp.max);
  console.log('Min: ' + filteredResult[0].temp.min);

  console.log('Filtered Result: ', filteredResult);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is doing it's thing. Could I get some explanation, I really want to learn this?

Comment: The code is very easy to understand if you know Javascript. I have used Filter() method, refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

Thats a javascript object, not a JSON.

If the attributes from the object are always the same, you can check its nested values.

```
obj.temp.min
obj.tem.max
obj.dt
```

**EDITED**
After seeing where you are retrieving the JSON Object from, you will have to get the array

```
{
    "city": {
        "id": 6940463,
        "name": "Altstadt",
        "coord": {
            "lon": 11.5752,
            "lat": 48.137
        },
        "country": "DE",
        "population": 0
    },
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.1094425,
    "cnt": 7,
    "list":[]
}
```

And you will retrieve the nested object like this

```
const finalObj=response.data.list.filter(obj => obj.dt === "The dt you want")
```

Comment: Thank you, your response is very helpful. But fetched obj.dt value will always be different. I could never predict it's value.

Comment: In the API Docs yo ucan see the following: dt Time of data calculation, unix, UTC. The date is always the "same". Only the day/month/year changes