# How to return min and max temperature for each day with OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: javascript

I am using a API same as this one : https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Belgrade,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02

I am trying to fetch data but I don't know how to filter data response for each day individually.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
fetch(
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Belgrade&&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=...."
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++)
    for (var temp in response[i]) {
        console.log("Min temp: "+response[i][temp].min);
        console.log("Max temp: "+response[i][temp].max);
    }
})
```

This is what I want to return:

```
Day: Today
Min_temp: 16
Max_temp: 20

Day: Tomorrow
Min_temp: 15
Max_temp: 21
```

Comment: See my response from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558170/how-to-filter-json-data-based-on-date-value-using-javascript/62558314#62558314

Comment: Please don't create duplicate accounts in Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Please don't create duplicate accounts in Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I'm assuming `i` is day offset, and that `response[i]` is an array of temperatures (hourly, or whatever) that are Numbers (not strings).  Then: `"min: "+response[i].reduce((min, num)=>((num<min)?(num):(min)))+"<br>max: "+response[i].reduce((max, num)=>((num>max)?(num):(max)))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `i` is day offset, and that `response[i]` is an array of temperatures (hourly, or whatever) that are Numbers (not strings).  Then:

```
"min: "+
response[i].reduce((min, num)=>((num<min)?(num):(min)))+
"<br>"+
"max: "+
response[i].reduce((max, num)=>((num>max)?(num):(max)))
```

Comment: Well?  Did it work/answer your question?
If so, please select and up-vote it.
Thanks!